# Query to find the records creating in last 30 mins and then the records created in last 1 hour

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a db of items from which I need to find the ones that were created in the last 30 mins, and want to order them by their `category`, then I want items that were created in the last 1 hour but I want to exclude the items found before, and again I want to order them by their `category`.

The current method I am using is using a union. I am not very sure if this is the best way. Something in my gut tells me there is a better way to do this, just don't know how.

Here's an example set of data and the query

```
id    category_id    created_at
1     1              10 mins ago
2     1              12 mins ago
3     2              10 mins ago
4     2              14 mins ago
5     1              40 mins ago
6     2              43 mins ago
7     1              34 mins ago
```

`(select * from items where created_at >= NOW() - 30 mins order by category_id) union (select * from items where created_at >= NOW() - 60 mins and created_at < NOW() - 30 mins order by category_id)`

The sample query is not syntactically correct obviously.

Create table
`create table items (id int(11), category_id int(11), created_at datetime);`

Output:

```
id    category_id    created_at
1     1              10 mins ago
2     1              12 mins ago
3     2              10 mins ago
4     2              14 mins ago
5     1              40 mins ago
7     1              43 mins ago
6     2              34 mins ago
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add `created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW() ,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)`

Comment: table create statement, and desired output

Comment: what do you mean with "group by" category? You want the count of the events per category?

Comment: @fthiella sorry, my bad. I meant order by

Comment: @amdixon Edited and added

Comment: @lad2025 yep, it's not the syntax I am worried about. I am trying to see if there is a way to improve this query, by not having to use union

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but the proper syntax is this:

```
SELECT "last 30 minutes" as t, category_id, count(*) as cnt
FROM items
WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
GROUP BY category_id
UNION ALL
SELECT "last 1 hour" as t, category_id, count(*) as cnt
FROM items
WHERE
  created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
  AND created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
GROUP BY category_id
```

...etc...

This query will count the events in the last 30 minutes, grouped by category_id, and then all events in the last hour but not in the last 30 minutes.

```
UNION ALL
```

is better than UNION on this context because UNION will return unique rows.

**Edit**

Based on your updated question, I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items
WHERE created_at>=NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
ORDER BY
  (created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) DESC,
  category_id
```

if you have more intervals then you can use this:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items
WHERE created_at>=NOW() - INTERVAL 120 MINUTE
ORDER BY
  (created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) DESC,
  (created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) DESC,
  category_id
```

Comment: @amit i've just updated my answer, i think it should be what you're looking for